# Данные из JSON в React

Tags: json, reactjs

Пытаюсь отрендерить простую таблицу на основе данных из JSON и получаю ошибку.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```js
const API = 'http://dev.frevend.com/json/users.json';

class OurTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
super(props);
  
this.state = {
  hits: []
};
  }

 componentDidMount() {
  fetch(API)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({
        hits: data, 
           isLoading: false,
         }));
  
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
 }

 render() {
  const { isLoading } = this.state;
        let data = this.state.hits;

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
     <p>Loading...</p>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
      return (
      <div className='wrapper'> 
            <table> 
              <thead>
               <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>surname</td>
                <td>desc</td>           
               </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {data.users.map(element =>
                  <tr key={element.id}>
                    <td>{element.id}</td>
                    <td>{element.name}</td>
                    <td>{element.surname}</td>
                    <td>{element.desc}</td>
                 </tr>
                )}
                </tbody>
           </table>
      </div> 
   );
  }
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<OurTable />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

образец кода в https://codepen.io/AndGreNik/pen/ebEYYe?editors=0010

Comment: Вы проверили данные которые Вам приходят с АПИ?

Comment: Вывел в консоль API, посмотрел, вроде бы всё, как надо.  Вывел стейт в консоль, затем data.  Все передается по цепочке корректно. Пошел дальше. Просто data выводит. Затем data.users выводит.  А вот data.users[0]  уже не хочет.

Answer (score 1):

```
const API = 'http://dev.frevend.com/json/users.json';
console.log(API);
class OurTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hits: {}, // не массив, а объект
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
        fetch(API)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        hits: data, 
        isLoading: false,
      })
    })
  }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, hits } = this.state;

    console.log(hits);

        if (isLoading) {
          return (
            <div>
                <p>Loading...</p>
            </div>
          );
        } else {
            return (
            <div className='wrapper'>   
            <table> 
              <thead>
               <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>surname</td>
                <td>desc</td>           
               </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {hits.users.map(element =>
                  <tr key={element.id}>
                    <td>{element.id}</td>
                    <td>{element.name}</td>
                    <td>{element.surname}</td>
                    <td>{element.desc}</td>
                 </tr>
                )}
              </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>  
            );
        }
    }
}

React.render(<OurTable />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Изначальное значение hits должно быть объект, а не массив.

Comment: Нашел причину, она заключалась в другом :)   В любом случае, спасибо за предложенную помощь. Сохранил json локально и все данные сразу отрендерились. Тут что-то связанное с асинхронностью или с методом componentDidMount. Но это всё пока для меня дремучий лес, нужно еще изучать. Еще один нюанс -  сайт отдает JSON через незащищенный протокол, и хром забирает данные только после установки специального расширения, а codepen вообще не может достучаться к этим данным.

Comment: Да, кодпен вообще их не получает, поэтому до конца определить в чем у вас проблема я не смог, но изначальная ошибка с `map` связана с тем что я сказал о начальном стейте